# How to connect to SQL Server from a C# program on another computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=192.168.0.100,1400;user=Users;password=password;database=Example1;integrated security = true;");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();

BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

public void loaddata()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmdatabbase = new SqlCommand(" select * from Example1.dbo.Users ;", con);

        sda.SelectCommand = cmdatabbase;

        sda.Fill(dbdataset);

        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

This is my code in C# Winforms application. On my computer it is working but from another computer it shows error (it can't load table in datagridview). I added rule in firewall and I enable tcp in SQL Server Configuration Manager but it still doesn't work! I tried every solution that found in internet but it didn't work.

[a busy cat http://non-98.ucoz.com/Untitled5.jpg](http://non-98.ucoz.com/Untitled5.jpg)

I saw this in another computer when running a program.

Comment: So....What's the exception message?

Comment: Give us more details. What is the error? On which line do you get ?

Comment: What's that `1400` in ip?

Comment: @Sudhakar Just want to ask....did you mess up " User2012384" with "user2971569"?

Comment: Try removing "integrated security = true", see if it works..

Comment: @User2012384: pardon me i was supposed to put that question to user2971569.

Comment: I removed and it worked thank you very much.

Comment: It worked in my virtual computer will it work on real computer ?  I will check it...

Comment: can I use public ip address and my port as my sql server name in managment studio

Comment: Is it possible to connect to sql server by tcp(from another computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the `integrated security` from `true` to `false`. Check this [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: can I use public ip address and my port as my sql server name in managment studio

Comment: I just used in your link  this "Connect via an IP address" constring And used my public ip and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to accessibility of the sever.Try either integrated security =False or update connection string